# Copying A Row from 1 excel sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to copy selected row from Sheet1 to Sheet2. Below code is overriding existing value in Sheet2 file. Please assist to stop override my existing values.

```
Sub CopySelection()

Dim xlSel As Excel.Range

Set xlSel = Excel.Application.Selection  
xlSel.Copy Excel.Application.Sheets("All_Data").Range("A1")

End Sub
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you are pasting to Cell "A1" , you need to change it where you don't have data. Where do you want your data copied to in Sheet "All_Data" ?

Comment: Hi Shai,, I want to copy data to All_data to next available row in All_Data sheet

Comment: try the code in my answer below (I hope this is what you meant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will copy the range selected in "**Sheet1**" (modify it to fit your sheet's name that holds the data to be copied), and then will paste it in Column A in the first available row in Sheet "**All_Data**".

Let me know if the code below (tested) works :

```
Sub CopySelection()

Dim Sht1                As Worksheet
Dim Sht2                As Worksheet
Dim xlSel               As Range
Dim LastRow             As Long

' modify "Sheet1" to your sheet source (where you make your Selection to copy)
Set Sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

' sheet "All_Data" is your target sheet (Where you paste the selection)
Set Sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("All_Data")

Set xlSel = Selection     

'option 1: find last row with data in Sheet "All_Data" at Column A
LastRow = Sht2.Cells(Sht2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'option 2: (less reliable) find last row with data in Sheet "All_Data" using UsedRange
'LastRow = Sht2.UsedRange.Rows(Sht2.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

' paste the copied range in Column A, the first row after row with data
xlSel.Copy Sht2.Range("A" & LastRow + 1)

End Sub
```

Comment: UsedRange is not reliable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba

Comment: @DavidZemens I agree, but the PO didn't specify the structure of his data, where does the last row with data is located (which Column). Also , the entire concept here (using `Selection`) is not that reliable. Im just trying to figure out what does the PO mean

Comment: I disagree, it's usually OK to use `Selection` as a way of gathering user input. The alternative is to code an `InputBox` object that asks for a selection, anyways. Further, you can always feel free to make additional improvements in the OP code when giving an answer :)

Comment: @DavidZemens ok, added the more reliable way finding the last row , per your recommendation :)

Comment: thank you Shai, It really worked. One more small help I would like to add a small timer in cell sheet1.  My need is as soon as my report is refreshed and if there is a new value added the timer should automatically start. Is it possible?

Comment: @RKVALU it is possible (I think), I have not used Timers for a long time. You should post a new post, with the edited code, and your new challenge

Comment: how to paste the values without formula's ?